# How to disable the header with filename and date when converting .ipynb to pdf with nbconvert?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am using `nbconvert` for converting my .ipynb into an .pdf file. When doing so the resulting .pdf file contains a header with the filename and the current date below. How can I disable that?

I was looking in the [docs](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but cannot find how to do it.

**CLI command**

```bash
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf filename.ipynb
```

**Actual**

[image]

**Wanted**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some helpful pointer in the [docs](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html#:%7E:text=the%20current%20template.-,a%20practical%20example). Just follow these steps:

1. Run `jupyter --paths` in your command-line.
2. Copy the path who looks like `/Users/username/.venv/venvName/share/jupyter` (I run nbconvert from a venv. Could be different for you).
3. Go to the path and duplicate the folder `latex`
4. Name the folder `hide_header` or whatever you want
5. Open `base.tex.j2` and delete the line `((* block maketitle *))\maketitle((* endblock maketitle *))`
6. Save
7. run `jupyter nbconvert --to pdf filename.ipynb --template=hide_header`

Answer (score 0):

@Max Hager provided a direct solution. Here is an indirect one:

1. Export `.ipynb` file to `LaTeX`.
2. Locate command `\title` in the `.tex` file by your favorite search tool.
3. Add `\date{}` after the `\title` command (you can also change the title, change date by `\date{1 January 1}`, and add author by `\author{me me me}`, etc).
4. Compile the `.tex` file.